# Euler's method to compute the number Napier's constant

Tags: constants

I am asking about the original way that Euler did to calculate Napier's constant, I heard that he was able to compute its first 23 decimals.

Comment: I'm not sure how Euler did it, but a naive approach such as Maclaurin's series seems to converge reasonably quickly (there are faster methods such as Brothers' formula, but that's more modern). Still, 23 decimal places seems extremely tedious using the tools of his day: do you have a reference to support this?

Comment: @Deepak I actually read it in a website here is the link
[link](https://plus.maths.org/content/where-does-e-come-and-what-does-it-do)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The article [Napier's $e$ - $e$ in Leonhard Euler's *Introductio*](http://www.maa.org/publications/periodicals/convergence/napiers-e-e-in-leonhard-eulers-introductio) says that Euler used the series
$$
e=1+{1\over 1}+{1^2\over 1\cdot 2}+{1^3\over 1\cdot 2\cdot 3}+\cdots
$$
to obtain
$$
e \approx 2.71828182845904523536028\cdots
$$

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant)#cite_note-28) cites [Euler's original text](https://books.google.com/books?id=jQ1bAAAAQAAJ&hl=en&pg=PA90#v=onepage&q&f=false), which confirms the story:

[image]

Comment: To get an accuracy of $23$ d.p. (as per the OP), Euler would've had to compute the reciprocal of factorials up to $24!$, presumably by hand. That seems... unlikely.

Comment: I suppose it's possible with repeated long division for an extremely determined and patient man haha.

Comment: @Deepak, you're underestimating Euler's calculation skills and determination!

Comment: LOL. But (apart from being a genius) was he a savant in calculation?

Comment: I'm really confused now, @lhf cited Euler's original text but on the other hand I'm with Deepak , I don't think that he was able to compute 23 d.p. from this formula

Comment: @Deepak, perhaps you could ask a separate question about the calculation skills of Euler and other famous mathematicians, probably at http://hsm.stackexchange.com?